# Function not defined when script appended to head and called from inline js

Tags: javascript

I've created this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dejerolozu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) with a demo of my problem.

```
var textFromHTTPRequest = '<html>'
    + '<head>'
      + '<script>'
        + 'function myFunc() { alert("works"); }'
      + '</script>'
    + '</head>'
    + '<body>'
      + '<a href="#" onmouseover="myFunc()">test</a>'
    + '</body>'
  + '</html>';

// Parse the text to dom element.
var parser = new DOMParser();
var el = parser.parseFromString(textFromHTTPRequest, "text/html");

// Get the script and contents of body.
var menuBody = el.firstChild.querySelectorAll('body > *');
var menuScript = el.firstChild.querySelector('head script');

// Insert the script into current head tag.
document.head.appendChild(menuScript);

// Insert the contents of body into current body.
for (var i = 0; i < menuBody.length; ++i) {
  document.body.appendChild(menuBody[i]);
}
```

The scenario it is replicating is using Fetch to pull up a HTML document.

The code parses the text, and then pulls out the body contents.  Something in the body uses an inline onmouseover.  So I also need to pull in the script tag.

But the onmouseover now doesn't work.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined
```

But if you use the Chrome Inspector - you can see the script has indeed been added.

(Please, let's not worry too much about why the page being fetched uses an onmouseover, I can't help that)

Comment: A html page by default will have `html`,`head`,& `body` tag. So is there any requirement to again create ?

Comment: The question is regarding the undefined function.  Don't poke holes in the example scenario, it is a minimal demonstration of the problem :)

Comment: So after doing this how many `head`, `body` & `html` tag you are seeing in the element source?

Comment: Just one of each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser will not "use" script that was not created by hitself.

#### You have 2 options:

1- create a new script and use the other's `.innerHTML`

```
var menuScript = document.createElement('script');
menuScript.innerHTML = el.firstChild.querySelector('head script').innerHTML;
```

**jsBin:** http://jsbin.com/dejerolozu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

2- use eval

You could run `eval` on that script, otherwise it will not be globalised by the browser:

```
// Insert the script into current head tag.
eval(menuScript.textContent);
```

**jsBin:** http://jsbin.com/zuwolelozo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself by using createElement and copying the script contents into that.  That works.  That'll do.

```
var menuScript = el.firstChild.querySelector('head script');

var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.innerHTML = menuScript.innerHTML;

// Insert the script into current head tag.
document.head.appendChild(script);
```